# update global variables from a parameter table without using `run` on a string

Tags: netlogo

As documented, using `run` on a string runs into problems when local variables (including procedure parameters) are involved.  So, what is the recommended way to achieve the following goal?

I have parameter tables (p1, p2, etc) specifying values for global variables, by name (i.e., table keys are strings, corresponding to the names of the global variables). Given a name (as a string) and a parameter table, I want to set the named global variable to the table value.  E.g., if we were to use `run`, and if the values were all numbers, we might do something like this:

```
to update [#nm #tbl]
    let %tval table:get #tbl #nm
    run (word "set " #nm " " %tval)
end
```

What is the recommended way to do this, avoiding strings (due to the warning in the docs)?

As an additional complication, some table values may be tasks.

Extension of the question:

Following up on my coment of Oct 9, I found that if I isolate the assignment to a procedure, I can also successively make global assignments with tasks.  E.g.,

```
to setGlobalTasks [#name #table]
  ;; #name : string, name of global variable
  ;; #table : table, maps names (strings) to values (reporter tasks)
  let %tval table:get #table #name
  run (word "set " #name " %tval")
end
```

Seth has provided some assurance that proceeding this way will continue to work in NetLogo when the assigned values are numbers.  Is this going to be risky when the assigned values are tasks?  Does it pose any risks in NetLogo 5.1?

Note: probably this extension of the question should be in the comments, but I could not format code blocks in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original approach, where `%tval` is outside of double quotes, only works with table values that are ordinary values like numbers, lists, or strings, values that can survive a round trip to string and back. (If you had trouble in practice, my guess would be that `run` got confused when you tried to combine it with `foreach`, as in the code you posted at http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/netlogo-devel/m5rnPEsxR44 . I believe this can be worked around by writing a standalone procedure like the one in your question.)

Your revised code, where `%tval` is inside the double quotes, and the whole thing is isolated in a separate procedure, is correct and should work for all possible table values. It should work fine in both NetLogo 5.0 and 5.1, and almost certainly in 6.0 too if there ever is a 6.0.

(In Tortoise, it wouldn't work, since `run` probably won't support strings at all in Tortoise.)

**Tangent on reflection:**

`run` on strings is kinda ugly. In situations where you want "reflective" setting of variables by name, where the name is stored in a string computed at runtime, it would be nice if there were an extension that supported this directly. The good news is, the code for the extension would be quite short and simple. The required methods within NetLogo, that the extension would call, already exist. The bad news is, writing a NetLogo extension of any kind is only easy if you're comfortable writing and compiling simple Java (or Scala) code. Anyway, it would be great if such a "reflection" extension existed. But in the meantime, you're safe with what you have.

Comment: You are correct: the approach I posted works when the table values are numbers but runs into problems when they are tasks.  I take it from what you said here that, despite the warning in the docs, I can count on this to continue to work with number values.

Comment: Taking a hint that moving the assignment into its own procedure
might smooth the way, I tried it also when the table values are
tasks.  It is working.  Should I expect future disappointment? I cannot get this comment to format code blocks, so I'll add it to my question.

Comment: My original answer was wrong. An extension isn't necessary. Your new revised code proves it. Nice catch! I've rewritten my answer.